# Read the JSON file before loading the core modules

Tags: json, angular

I am using angular to build my Project. I want to change the API endpoint after building the Project. For this I have created the JSON file in the assets folder and all of the service files read the data from that file. The data in the JSON file can also be changed after building the Project. But the problem is that API endpoint is required in the **core.module.ts** which is executed before the JSON file is loaded. So the data from the JSON file is always undefined. Is it possible to load the JSON file before the **core.module.ts**, so that no problem occurs.

**JSON File**

```
{
    "env": {
         "name": "dev"
    },
    "apiServer": {
        "url": "/api"
    }
}
```

**app.config.ts**

```
export class AppConfig {
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    load() {
        const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: Response) => {
                AppConfig.settings = response.json();
                resolve();
             }).catch((response: any) => {
                 reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
             });
        });
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export function initializeApp(appConfig: AppConfig) {
    return () => appConfig.load();
}

providers: [
    AppConfig,
    { provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeApp,
    deps: [AppConfig], multi: true },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },
]
```

Comment: Can you provide some code and the details about your environment

Answer (score 0):

The APP_INITIALIZER injection token is the best way to run your code. You need to hook into the application init process and load. To do that, you have to create AppConfig in the `app.module.ts` file:

```
 export function appConfigFactory(provider: AppConfig): Function {  
  return () => provider.load();
}



  providers: [
    HttpModule,
    StartupService,
    Title,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory:appConfigFactory,
      deps: [AppConfig],
      multi: true
    }
```

So, I recommend you to read these :

https://devblog.dymel.pl/2017/10/17/angular-preload/

https://www.cicoria.com/ensuring-initializing-and-server-side-configuration-with-angular/

To understand more read this:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/
https://hackernoon.com/hook-into-angular-initialization-process-add41a6b7e

Comment: The data is correctly loaded in the component. I want to load the data into the core.module.ts. I have implemented the code you shared. But it exectues after the core.module.ts

Comment: Read this to show you how to run it before http.get call:https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/

Comment: Are sure that you do `export function AppConfig` in the `app.module.ts`

Comment: Ofcourse I have implemented it. It works fine the only problem is that it is loaded after the core.module.ts which cause errors

Comment: In your `app.module.ts'  the ` useFactory:`  should match the `provider:` in export  and you should add the both to `app.module.ts`

Comment: I have updated the code in app.module.ts check it and point out any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185642/discussion-between-i-th-and-fiza-khan).